# Error: Cannot read property 'insertAdjacentHTML' of null in console

Tags: javascript

I have some code, but the problem is it is giving me an error: *' Cannot read property 'insert-adjacent HTML' of null'*. It comes when I put this:

```
let lastone = document.querySelector('.calender p:last-of-type');
lastone.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", getDayMarkUp());


function getDayMarkUp() {
   <p class="day"></p>
}
```

But I have no error when I put this:

```
let lastone = document.querySelector('p:last-of-type');
lastone.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", getDayMarkUp());


function getDayMarkUp() {
   <p class="day"></p>
}
```

HTML:

```
<p></p> <!-- I need this paragraph! -->
<section class="calendar">
    <p>sun</p>
    <p>Mon</p>
    <p>Tue</p>
    <p>Wed</p>
    <p>Thur</p>
    <p>Fri</p>
    <p>Sat</p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
</section>
```

Can you tell me why the error is coming, and if possible how you solve it?

Comment: Are your paragraphs children of calendar?

Comment: Please include your html.

Comment: Try using `.querySelectorAll()` for more parametars.

Comment: @DaniloIvanovic — Since the problem is that sometimes there is at least 1 result and sometimes there are 0 results, that won't help. 0 will still be 0.

Comment: I Added HTML for the question.

Comment: yes, @imvain2. My 'paragraphs' are children of 'calendar'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have multiple possibilities:

1. Paragraph with class "calender":

```js
document.querySelector('p.calender:last-of-type')
```

2. Element with the classes "p" and "calender":

```js
document.querySelector('.p.calender:last-of-type')
```

3. Select all elements either paragraph elements or calender class:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.calendar, p:last-of-type')
```

4. Paragraph inside an element with class "calender" will use your error-throwing code, so obviously that is not what you want.

Comment: one and two might not solve my problem, 3 would halfway solve my problem, and 4 is what I am trying to do.

Comment: If 4 is the one you want, then the error is most likely because there is no paragraph inside `.calender`

Comment: Typo noticed: you selected calender but the html says calendar